# How to make two Java arrays correspond to each other (Beginner)

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a simple command-line application where student courses and the corresponding grades the students achieved for them are inputted. I have created two arrays - one to store the student courses, and another to store the corresponding grades.

```
String[] courses = {"Computer Science", "Maths", "English"};
int[] grades = {5, 4, 3}
```

How do I make the each grade correspond to each subject, so Computer Science has a grade of 5.

I'm guessing theres a much more efficient way of doing this, but as a newbie I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Ideally I want to store all the info in one array.

Comment: Maybe create a class that has two fields, `name` and `grade` to group things up?

Comment: Well, if your teacher imposes the design, what do you want us to do for you? A "much more efficient way" wouldn't use the imposed design, so there's not much we can do.

Comment: Thanks for your review! @Crowie . I will remove it right away . I dont mean to be harsh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to bind those two arrays. In Java it's better to use objects. If you want to storage those data together (grades and courses) - create a class, after that creat objects that class and put them into array, like the following code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Grades[] grades = {
            new Grades("Computer Science", 5),
            new Grades("Math", 4),
            new Grades("English", 3)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
        System.out.println(grades[i]);
    }
}
}

class Grades{
String subjectName;
int grade;

public Grades(String subjectName, int grade) {
    this.subjectName = subjectName;
    this.grade = grade;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Grade is: " + this.grade + "\n" +
            "Subject is: " + this.subjectName;
}
}
```

If you know what extension is the code above gives you enough information to realize your diagram, good luck!